# hosted JS files not loading inside a android webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, webview

I just created a web page and added jquery and css files. Now as I load this page inside a webview of my android app. The CSS files seams to load very well, however the JS files are causing an issue and breaking the whole page layout.

```
<link href="<%: Url.Content("~/favicon.ico") %>" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.3.min.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />  
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<link href="~/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  

// This works fine  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>  

//this doesn't work  
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>  


//neither does this one  
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have this up in any URL?

Comment: Yes I do http://217.17.237.165:85/HRM

Comment: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/21941/javascript-include-in-webview-not-working#answer-215881 try the solution there I mean renaming the js files

Comment: Sure I will try this out, however my web app is developed in asp.net mvc4.

Comment: @skv Tried, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was relative path, once we resolve the path it would work well and load the contents. Below changes were helpful and it works like a charm now.

```
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")%>"></script>
<script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js")%>"></script>
```